# Estimating sunset time from Earth's radius

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

i have some issues with this. Could anyone explain me if it is right /wrong

[image]? that is the link/image of my work

-You are lying on a beach, your eyes 20 cm above the
sand. Just as the Sun sets, fully disappearing over the horizon,
you immediately jump up, your eyes now 150 cm above the
sand, and you can again just see the top of the Sun. If you count
the number of seconds until the Sun fully disappears
again, you can estimate the Earth’s radius. But for this Problem,
use the known radius of the Earth to calculate the time t.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you very much for .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of $x,\,y$ is correct but overly complicated as they're in right-angled triangles, so you don't need the cosine rule. (Since both cosines are very close to $1$, we also have the approximations $x\approx\sqrt{40/R}$ etc. *in radians*.) You're also right that each degree takes $4$ minutes to traverse.

But your result contains a spurious factor of $2$. You seem to think the Sun only disappears when angles of $2x$ or $2y$ have been subtended, rather than when angles of $x$ or $y$ have been subtended, taking us to the point where the line of vision is tangential to Earth's surface.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. In this case will the result be negative? I am new at all this, this is the last problem on the Chapter 1 of my physics' book. 
I wonder if this is too hard or if it could be solved in a much easier way. It took me 4 hours to get to this point. I am also not sure how to fix it...